What's difference between pyspark.DataFrame.checkpoint() and pyspark.RDD.checkpoint()?
I'm currently struggling with spark checkpoints and trying to understand what's the difference between DataFrame and RDD checkpoints.
To make it clear: after DataFrame.checkpoint() spark creates file on hdfs, and it is something like hdfs:///sdfasd-dfasdf-dfasdf/rdd-2, - so it saves RDD of DataFrame. The same thing saves after checkpointing RDD.
So, the main question: does this files differ? and will spark use this checkpoint for dataframe if we made RDD.checkpoint() (if they are the same files).
And also I have some side question: for RDD there are getCheckpointFile() method which allows to get checkpoint file full path. Are there any chance to get the same for DataFrame? Because there are no box method.

Well, the RDD an DF are different structures but the core thing is lineage truncation and saving state of an RDD or DF to disk. Why? 1) Performance for Catalyst on, say, iterative algorithms and 2) Fault tolerance rebuild aspects in case of node failure.
In that sense there is no difference.

Thanks for your answer, but actually when I do df.checkpoint() spark saves rdd serialized file named rdd-213 or sth like that. SO the main question was is it the same file for df and rdd?

What does it matter?
